# How to disable track stick dell lattitude without using a mouse

Tags: dell

The [track stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) is jamming the cursor down in the lower right corner. Root shell command is only way to control - xinput not installed - don't know how to do much with Ubuntu.  XP not working too due to cursor...